# can not close window with the x button disabled in the upper right corner

Tags: winapi, window

```
int result= Win32Api.SendMessage(intPtr, Win32Api.WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
Win32Api.SendMessage(intPtr, Win32Api.WM_COMMAND, 0, 0);
Win32Api.DestroyWindow(intPtr);
```

[image: window image]

[image: C# Call win32]

The handle is 000A0274 as shown

This pop-up box is opened by autocad. Another C # program obtains the handle to this window and uses win32 api to close the window

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You should really improve your question: Add a language tag (at the very least) and show a bit more of your code - for example, how do you get the value of `intPtr` (which would seem a likely cause of the problem, from the little you *have* posted).

Comment: It seems this window like user to choose "YES“ or ”NO“ instead of close it directly. Do you mind sharing the reason of closing it programmatically and directly?